# What is the difference between academic and business registration when applying to conferences?

Tags: conference, pre-registration

I have been trying to register for a conference abroad and it is my first time to do so.
So I wanted to ask what they mean by academic or business registration when applying.

Comment: Well, are you attending as an academic or on behalf of a business? Any distinction they make is totally up to them.

Answer (score 2):

Academic conferences, such as those sponsored by ACM (Association for Computing Machinery) are primarily for academics (faculty) and students. However, some business researchers also attend (IBM, Google, ...) and may, in principle, pay a different rate (higher). Some others, such as book sellers also attend, looking both for sales and for authors working on textbooks and such. At some conferences, governmental researchers also attend and might be considered academics or not.

Conferences are expensive to run, so those that have the most financial backing (for-profit business) might be expected to pay more. Students usually get a discount and might be able to attend for free, though as volunteers in the running of the conference.

Comment: Just to be sure it is understood: "Academics" in this context means students or people working for academic institutions, such as universities or research institutes. Students sometimes have their own category.

Comment: @Snijderfrey, yes, students qualify as do faculty. For "Research Institutes" there may be a difference for governmental, non-profit, for-profit, etc. depending on the individual rules.

Comment: so do you mean if Iam a doctor(Physician) attending a medical conference then I should choose Academic not Business ?

Comment: @JanBarengy, that isn't quite the same. Ask the conference committee. There are too many possibilities. Medical conferences may be a special case and there might be varieties of them.